# Apache2 + mod_wsgi + python 3.6 not responding

Tags: django, apache2, python-3.6

I'm deploying a Django app with python 3.6 and virtualenv in an Ubuntu 18.4 server. This is my apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.com
    Redirect / https://myapp.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myapp.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/apache2/ssl/myapp.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/myapp.comv.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/myapp.com.crt"
    SSLProxyEngine On

    Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/myapp/assets/
    Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/myapp/data/
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/myapp/data>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/myapp/assets>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/myapp>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-path=/home/ubuntu/myapp:/home/ubuntu/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup myapp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/myapp/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

if I run `mod_wsgi-express module-config` I get

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/ubuntu/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/home/ubuntu/myapp/venv"
```

which is the virtualenv I want to use.

Nonetheless when I try to access myapp.com I get timedout and there is nothing in error.log or access.log

error.log

```
[Sun Sep 30 11:42:37.066273 2018] [core:notice] [pid 628:tid 140584565169088] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Sep 30 11:42:39.728096 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 628:tid 140584565169088] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Sep 30 11:42:39.812550 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 882:tid 140042546797504] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.0g mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Sep 30 11:42:39.812642 2018] [core:notice] [pid 882:tid 140042546797504] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

access.log

```
51.38.12.21 - - [30/Sep/2018:08:20:14 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11192 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
37.135.181.196 - - [30/Sep/2018:10:40:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3477 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
37.135.181.196 - - [30/Sep/2018:10:40:24 +0000] "GET /icons/ubuntu-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3623 "http://3.120.98.140/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
37.135.181.196 - - [30/Sep/2018:10:40:25 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 503 "http://3.120.98.140/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
```

I tried adding `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` to my apache config file but the result is the same.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's all that ProxyPass stuff for?

Comment: @DanielRoseman we use it to server static files. I just tested removing it and the result is the same. I'll edit my question and remove it for the sake of clarity

Answer (score 0):

Since no-one has attempted an answer and I've been trying to do the same thing (only on CentOS), for me it was SELinux.

If you have SELinux enabled (seems unlikely on Ubuntu), it might be denying read access to the wsgi file, though I'd expect your httpd error log and selinux audit log to show that.  I had to change the context type:

```
$ ls -Z ~/myproject
drwxrwxr-x. admin admin unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 myprojectenv
-rwxrw-r--. admin admin unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 myproject.wsgi
$ chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t ~/myproject/myproject.wsgi
$ ls -Z ~/myproject/myproject.wsgi
-rwxrw-r--. admin admin unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 myproject.wsgi
```

I my case I also overlooked that my test project needed to define a function called 'application' instead of something else, and I renamed it to .wsgi from .py (though, I think that's just convention).

The mod_wsgi documentation's section on checking your installation was also quite helpful, specifically making sure I wasn't running a mod_wsgi compiled against a different version of python or something silly like that.

https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html